# Dart timer change duration dynamically

Tags: performance, loops, flutter, asynchronous, dart

I have the following dart code:

```
var seconds;
// some stream defined elsewhere
stream.listen((data){
  seconds = data;
});
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: seconds), (timer) {
      // do something here
 });
```

How do I make the timer respect the dynamic durations?

Comment: what is " dynamic duration"? every time different period? if so, how do you want to specify that?

Comment: @pskink the stream emits different seconds value from time to time hence making the duration dynamic. More like the period at one time is 5 seconds and at a different time its 9 seconds

Comment: then stop "old" timer (if any) and create new one inside `listen` callback

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dart/flutter how to change the timer inside periodic after every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62183435/dart-flutter-how-to-change-the-timer-inside-periodic-after-every-time)

Answer (score 0):

For the old code, the **timer** will only be called once even if the **seconds** variable changes.
So you need to create a new timer every time data comes to you from the **stream**

**like this:**

```
// some stream defined elsewhere
stream.listen((data){
 Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: data), (timer) {
      // do something here
 });
});
```

And if you only want one-timer, you should stop the old-timer